# Show a div when at least one checkbox is checked, but hide after last checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use these scripts to show a div when at least one checkbox on the page is checked.

At pageload all checkboxes are not checked. If the user checks one, a hidden div shows.
I used two scripts for this.

The first found here http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
<script>
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  $( "#count" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " zijn") + " aangevinkt!" );

};
countChecked();

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>
```

The second script shows a hidden div #maak_deel

```
<script>
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#maak_deel").fadeIn();
  });

</script>
```

I have two questions, due to the fact that I am new in this.

1) How can I combine these two in one script (to make my code more clean)

2) How can I make the div #maak_deel hide if the user checks one (=div shows) but then makes up his mind and unchecks again. Now nothing happens, I want the div to disappear again. I tried toggle, but that gives a wrong effect.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the hiding and showing code in the counting function.

```
<script>
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length; //n now contains the number of checked elements.
  $( "#count" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " zijn") + " aangevinkt!" ); //show some text
  if(n == 0){
    $("#maak_deel:visible").fadeOut(); //if there are none checked, hide only visible elements
  } else {
    $("#maak_deel:hidden").fadeIn(); //otherwise (some are selected) fadeIn - if the div is hidden.
  }

};
countChecked();

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>
```

This must be of course executed after DOM is loaded, so either at the end of  or wrap the code in jQuery's $(document).ready(function(){ // code goes here; });